# Extending Styles via ClassName Prop in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a custom box component which I want users to be able to override the default styling, by passing a className prop. The problem is, the base styles are never overridden, but styles that aren't already in the base class are applied to the component. I want scenario where if the base class has a background colour of 'blue' and a user passes a background colour of 'red', the user's values should take precedence

Box.js

```
import styles from "./Box.module.css";

const Box = ({ className }) => {
  const classnames = [styles.base, className].join(" ").trim();
  return <div className={classnames}></div>;
};

export default Box;
```

Box.module.css

```
.base {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

App.js

```
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import Box from "./components/Box";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Box className={styles.red} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.module.css

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I noticed that moving the styles import below the Box import in App.js, makes the background 'red' always. I need a reliable way to implement extendable styles for custom components

Comment: Order of import, and CSS selector specificity matter most here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the order in which the CSS files are imported. Imagine these lines were in a single CSS file; take Example A VS. Example B:

Example A:

```css
.base {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Example B:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.base {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

In Example A, the `.red` class will take precedence over the `.base` class regardless of the order in which the classNames are applied to the `div` in `Box`; the opposite is true for Example B.

To combat this, style libraries like [MUI](https://mui.com/) often use "style engines", which allow you to write code that seems like inline styles but compiles down to CSS files, and which the user can choose to "inject" later, allowing their own CSS to override the library's. You could try looking into one of those solutions, such as [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled), or, if that's above the scope of what you're looking for, you could:

A) have your end user import the `Box` file before their own CSS

B) have your end user import `Box`'s CSS file on their own, and pass it to `Box` themselves

C) have your end user up the specificity of their CSS, and lower your own (possibly using the `:where` selector)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Can you provide a simple example of how the desired behaviour is achieved in component libraries, using a style engine like emotion? Tried searching through the MUI codebase, but it gets quite confusing.